# React/Typescript: How to get json file data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

How can I read data from a json file in state? I know how to do this in react only but failing to do it in react using typescript. Should I place it in state in the first place if it's not going to change anyways?

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import * as data from '../../team.json';

interface Props {
  //props
}

interface State {
   nextRacers: Array<object>;
   jockeys: Array<any>;
}

console.log(data) // I can see my data here in dev tools

export class Race extends React.Component<Props, State> {

  constructor(props: Props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          jockeys: data, 
          nextRacers: [],
      };
  }
  
}
```

**Error I get;**

> Type '{ jockeys: typeof "*.json"; nextRacers: never[]; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly'.
>     Types of property 'jockeys' are incompatible.
>       Type 'typeof "*.json"' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
>         Property 'includes' is missing in type 'typeof "*.json"'.

I'm new to typescript & react and the syntax is still messing with my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to cast `data` to `any`, and then you need cast it again to the type of the `jockeys` field, which is `Array<any>`. Try updating the assignment to `this.state` like so:

```
this.state = {
    jockeys: data as any as Array<any>, 
    nextRacers: [],
};
```

Comment: I get >Type 'typeof "*.json"' cannot be converted to type 'any[]'.
  Property 'includes' is missing in type 'typeof "*.json"'.

Comment: tslint stubbornly gives me a >[tslint] Type declaration of 'any' loses type-safety. Consider replacing it with a more precise type. (no-any) warning. How can I not make my array of `any` type.

Comment: You cannot cast a JSON module directly to type `Array<any>`. You must first cast it to `any`. I think you may want to consider disabling the `no-any` TSLint rule for this use case. The code will still compile.

Comment: Thanks. Otherwise I just changed `any` to `object` and it compiled

Comment: That's good to know. I'm glad that fixed it. Thanks for the accepted answer.